# Modifying Python Module

Tags: python, module

This is the codes in "Main.py"

```
import au
import webbrowser
scc=input().split()
au.sc1[0]=scc[0]
au.sc1[1]=scc[1]
webbrowser.open(au.sc(a))
```

This is the codes in "au.py"

```
sc1 = ['','']
def sc(sc):
    if sc==sc1[0]:
        return sc1[1]
```

What I want to do is to make new list in "au.py" so that the user can make many shortcuts as they want, also is there anyways to save the data even though you end the the program? So that the next time you run "Main.py" all the shortcuts are still saved and you don't need to write it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module are not made to save variables or list content. You have to consider saving to a file, and reading from it.